# When is Geographic Weighted Regression used and why?

Tags: regression

I am currently trying to better understand what geographic weighted regression is, and what it is useful for. I have been reading up on it, but would like to get others people's views on it and see what they have to say.

I would like to know when you would want to use, and why is it useful? I graduated with my degree in GIS last December, and have been in the GIS workforce for almost a year now. I started out in utilities, but am now in the 911 field, so I am trying to learn more about hot spots, and using weighted regression.

Comment: Could you share some of the research you've been doing (links / summaries)? Better yet, how might GWR relate to a specific problem or application you're facing? As it stands, your question may be too broad for many people to want to tackle it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no actual problem to be solved and it falls into the “I’m curious if other people feel like I do” category from our [Help](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page.

Answer (score 1):

GWR accounts for spatial non-stationary events, so ideally the number of 911 calls as an dependent variable could be based on things like income, age, race, etc.  the r2 gives the strength of the model, there are a number of parameters which can be used to identify the strength of the model, such as the akaike information criterion, etc.

Seeing spatial autocorrelation in an OLS should lead you to execute a GWR.